# Why are black squares appearing in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs

I'm developing an application in ExtJS 4.2.0 and using Chrome as my development browser. I've noticed that when I hide dropdown menus black squares appear in their place. I'm assuming this isn't supposed to happen! Has anyone else experienced this?

I'm using ExtJs 4.2.0 and Chrome 27.0.1453.94 m.

Thanks!

## UPDATE

After some investigation I've found that it happens when using ExtJS in conjunction with the Javascript Infovis Toolkit (http://philogb.github.io/jit/). I've managed to recreate the problem reliably here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Black Box Experiment</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/jit-yc.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function(){
        //some data to put in the chart
        var data = {
            "name": "Test1",
            "data": {
                "id": "1"
            }
        };

        //Create a new ST instance  
        var st = new $jit.ST({
            injectInto: 'infovis',  
            duration: 0,  
            levelDistance: 50,  
            orientation: "top",
            Navigation: {  
              enable:false,  
              panning:true  
            },  
            Node: {  
                height: 30,  
                width: 150,
                autoHeight: false,
                autoWidth: false,
                type: 'rectangle',  
                overridable: true
            },  

            NodeStyles: {  
                enable: true,
                stylesHover: {  
                    'color': '#dd3333'  
                },  
                duration: 700  
            },


            Edge: {  
                type: 'bezier',  
                overridable: true  
            }
        });  
        //load json data  
        st.loadJSON(data);
        st.compute(); 

        //emulate a click on the root node.  
        st.onClick(st.root);

        //create our extjs panel for the buttons
        Ext.create(Ext.panel.Panel,{
            title: "Test panel",
            width: 300,
            height: 100,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Open/Close Menu',
                    menu: [
                        {text: 'button 1'},
                        {text: 'button 2'},
                        {text: 'button 3'},
                        {text: 'button 4'},
                        {text: 'button 5'},
                        {text: 'button 6'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Click to open an alert - a black square will appear',
                    handler: function(){
                        Ext.Msg.alert("Test","A black box should now be appearing where the menu button is.");
                    }
                }
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="infovis" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: auto; overflow: scroll; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the example above, take the following steps to recreate the problem:
1. Click on the "Open/Close Menu" button twice (once to open, once to close)
2. Click on the "Alert" button. A black box should appear in the position of the menu that we've just closed.

Does anyone else see this?

Comment: Without code to test it is likely a moderator will close this question.

Comment: OK, I will try to create a test case for this - it's part of quite a complicated app so I can't just paste it all in. However it is literally just closing a normal everyday menu that causes the problem, and it works absolutely fine on other browsers (FF, IE, Opera). It even works fine on versions of Chrome up to 26. I think it's probably a browser issue...

Comment: I've seen similar during javascript animations on mobile chrome (on android), but only *during* the animation - they don't persist afterwards... interested to see if you can reproduce this consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this exact same problem. It seems to be a (Windows only) Chrome bug relating to the the `visibility: hidden` css rule Ext uses by default to hide the dropdown.

A workaround is to change the css hide technique in the menu config:

```
{
  ...
  menu: {
    items: [
      ...
    ], 
    hideMode: 'display'
  }
}
```

Comment: btw we're not using infovis, but we do have 2D canvas & webgl things on the page.

Comment: Fantastic! It worked! Fortunately for me there were only 2 menus affected by this bug so it wasn't too much of a pain! Are the Chrome team aware of this bug?

Comment: not sure... there is [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76126), but it was fixed a while back.

Comment: Are there any advantages/disadvantages to using hideMode:'display'? I too found that doing that solved the black square problem, and I'm considering just overriding Ext.menu.Menu to make it a default for all my menus. I don't want to run into any other problems though because of it.

Comment: @zeke Not really.  The only difference between display:none and visibility:hidden is that visibility:hidden items still appear in the layout, but that doesn't apply to absolutely positioned things.  Display:none would be a better default AFAICS

Answer (score 0):

Im going thru the exact same thing with Ext js 4.0.1

Other browsers than Chrome behave as expected.

Thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

To apply this fix to all menus, rather than having to set it individually, you can just override the Ext.menu.Menu class:

```
Ext.override(Ext.menu.Menu,{
  hideMode: 'display'
});
```

This completely solved the problem for me, as there were actually a lot of menus affected by this.